# How to use modernizr with jquery

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I have problem when putting the jquery script and modernizr in the same head will make the thing's that use modernizr will not function. But at the same time, i need to use the jquery for my dropdown menu.
Here my head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/submenu/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script> 
<script src="js/grid/modernizr.custom.js"> </script>
```

Is there any way that make both script will work?

Comment: This isn't likely to be because you have modernizr and jquery both called. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Modernizr needs to be the first script loaded.

Comment: Yes. Ideally you would also move jquery and related scripts to the end of `<body>` - rather than in `<head>`

Comment: If i move the jquery to end of     <body> my dropdown will not work